# Angular navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() does not exist

Tags: angular

I wish to record on my website the screen of the user.
The problem is that when I want to get the screen of the user, I use `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` but apparently it does not exist on type "MediaDevices".
I did a lot of research before posting here but can't seem to find an answer.
I also tried this:

```
let mediaConstraints = {
      video: {
        mediaSource: "screen"
      },
      audio: true
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
```

and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Any errors? You know that returns a promise right?

Comment: yes, I can't compile because the function doesn't exist. what should I do?

Comment: Go step by step. Is navigator an object (console it)?

Comment: look, I got it to work with camera to record the user camera. but does not work with screen

Comment: I really need an answer please